# How do I add support for js 6 and above in JMeter jsr223 sampler?

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsr223

I am using Jmeter 5.4 but with this also I am not able to use js 6 and above in JSR223 sampler.
My problem at hand is I have an SDK which supports js 6 and above and I would like to make use of this sampler to test the sdk.
Is there a way I can upgrade the js 5.1 to 6 or above?

Answer (score 0):

Add the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
nashorn.args=--language=es6
```

and upon JMeter restart you should be able to use ECMAScript 6 syntax

More information:

- [Nashorn jsr223 engine notes](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Tried using this but did not work

Comment: @SharadMalpani plz do share if you found a way to run es6 script in jsr223. Thanks